# Unable to Setup Next.js 14 with Apollo Client GraphQL

Tags: reactjs, next.js, apollo-client, graphqlclient

I am new to Next.js & GraphQL, need to work on a project using both. So trying to setup a dummy project with Next.js(JavaScript, React), Apollo Client, Apollo Server. The Server side is up and running without hassle. But Client side is not able to load Apollo Server data in UI, I was able create a basic API call from client side and load the data but not able to make it render using `ApolloProvider` / `ApolloWrapper`.

I have tried to follow many articles available online, but none worked. The final one which looked promising and easy but written for TypeScript - [Medium Article](https://medium.com/womenintechnology/building-a-nextjs-backend-with-graphql-and-mongodb-fa6ca1307478) & [Repo](https://github.com/Stephany-Doris/NextJS-GraphQL-MongoDB-app/tree/main). I tried to follow it but still getting below error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dY5IR.png)

**`src/app/layout.js`**

```js
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { ApolloProvider } from "@apollo/client";
// import { ApolloWrapper } from "../lib/apollo-wrapper";
import client from "../lib/client";


const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
      <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
          <ApolloProvider client={client}>{children}</ApolloProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
  );
}
```

**`src/lib/client.js`**

```js
import { ApolloClient, HttpLink, InMemoryCache, from } from "@apollo/client";

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
  uri: '/'
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    uri: "http://localhost:4000/",
    link: from([httpLink])
  });
  
export default client;
```

**`Dependencies from package.json`**

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.9.0-rc.1",
    "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support": "^0.8.0",
    "graphql": "^16.8.1",
    "next": "14.1.0",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.1.0",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use Apollo Client with the App Router, you have to use it with the `@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support` library. Refer to this post - [NextJS (AppRouter), Apollo (Client), error on using ApolloProvider in root layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78141435/nextjs-approuter-apollo-client-error-on-using-apolloprovider-in-root-layou)

Seems like you added `@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support` in your dependencies but didn't use it at all. Also, your `@apollo/client` library may need to be updated to the latest version - `npm install @apollo/client@latest`

To wrap your `RootLayout` with `ApolloProvider`, try following (refer to https://www.npmjs.com/package/@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support for more info):

First, create a new file `src/app/ApolloWrapper.jsx`:

```
"use client";

import { ApolloLink, HttpLink } from "@apollo/client";
import {
  ApolloNextAppProvider,
  NextSSRInMemoryCache,
  NextSSRApolloClient,
  SSRMultipartLink,
} from "@apollo/experimental-nextjs-app-support/ssr";

function makeClient() {
  const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: "http://localhost:4000/api/graphql",
    fetchOptions: { cache: "no-store" },
  });

  return new NextSSRApolloClient({
    cache: new NextSSRInMemoryCache(),
    link:
      typeof window === "undefined"
        ? ApolloLink.from([
            new SSRMultipartLink({
              stripDefer: true,
            }),
            httpLink,
          ])
        : httpLink,
  });
}

export function ApolloWrapper({ children }) {
  return (
    <ApolloNextAppProvider makeClient={makeClient}>
      {children}
    </ApolloNextAppProvider>
  );
}
```

Now you can wrap your `RootLayout` in this wrapper component in the `src/app/layout.js` file:

```
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { ApolloWrapper } from "./ApolloWrapper";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "Create Next App",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <ApolloWrapper>{children}</ApolloWrapper>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```